# Jenkins stuck on using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket server credentials

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I am trying to setup Jenkins (for the first time) on a Mac.

I have installed the defaults, and added the `Blue Ocean`, from Blue Ocean created a new pipeline, following what I had to do to connect to a Bitbucket Cloud repo.

Jenkins could list all my Bitbucket repos, and also when I go to Bitbucket it appear to have added a SSH key..

[image]

However, whenever I try to build, it gets as far as `using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket server credentials` and just never gets any further.

The only way I could get Jenkins to checkout at all was to create a free style project and manually enter a private SSH key...

[image]

However, from what I have read so far, it is a `Pipeline` I would prefer to use, so I can have my steps in source control via a `Jenkinsfile`.

When using the Pipeline, I just don't seem to be able enter the private key anywhere as I did for the freestyle, and I have no idea what is going wrong.

I have been searching for hours, and nothing helps. I have set up other SSH keys all over the place, but nothing works.

How can I diagnose (logs or anything) this very first and most essential step if being able to clone a (private) repo from Bitbucket?

### Update 1

Tried just using a Git connection rather than Bitbucket.

It gave a a ssh key which I entered, it did not work. The tried using https, where it then asked me for my user name and password.

This then gave "Git credential validation failed with unexpected error. Please try again."

### Update 2

Tried another repo in my bitbucket and it worked fine first up!

Must be something wrong with the one I am trying to use. Perhaps because I haven't a branch called master (as I was trying to make a new main branch).

Knowing this, will persevere with seeing if there is something wrong with this particular repo

### Update 3

I created a master branch in the repo having the problems. I then created a new pipeline (via Blue Ocean). Seems to find and add, and when I go to to Bitbucket cloud UI, I can see Jenkins has added the new Jenkins file with my new step in it.

Back into Jenkins, I see the following...

```
        Scan Multibranch Pipeline Log
    Started by user Peter C
    [Sat May 25 08:37:44 AWST 2019] Starting branch indexing...
    Connecting to https://bitbucket.org using PC2007/****** (Bitbucket server credentials)
    Repository type: Git
    Looking up {c7e01be7-0e9d-421f-95d2-30fbe43170fa}/myapp for branches
    Checking branch ionic4 from {c7e01be7-0e9d-421f-95d2-30fbe43170fa}/myapp
          ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found
        Skipped
    Checking branch master from {c7e01be7-0e9d-421f-95d2-30fbe43170fa}/myapp
          ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
        Met criteria
    Scheduled build for branch: master
    Checking branch ionic3-master from {c7e01be7-0e9d-421f-95d2-30fbe43170fa}/myapp
          ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found
        Skipped
    Checking branch offline-cache from {c7e01be7-0e9d-421f-95d2-30fbe43170fa}/myapp
          ‘Jenkinsfile’ not found
        Skipped

      4 branches were processed
    Looking up {c7e01be7-0e9d-421f-95d2-30fbe43170fa}/myapp for pull requests

      0 pull requests were processed
    [Sat May 25 08:37:47 AWST 2019] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 3.1 sec
    Finished: SUCCESS
```

Finally it looks like it start to get the repo, but then at the end I have...

```
                Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.18 MiB | 34.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.21 MiB | 35.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.31 MiB | 47.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.39 MiB | 53.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.42 MiB | 56.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.48 MiB | 59.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.51 MiB | 56.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.57 MiB | 53.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.62 MiB | 52.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.68 MiB | 52.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.70 MiB | 46.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.75 MiB | 48.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.78 MiB | 43.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.79 MiB | 39.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.82 MiB | 34.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.87 MiB | 29.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.90 MiB | 33.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.93 MiB | 30.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 46.95 MiB | 31.00 KiB/s   
            Receiving objects:  81% (6074/7483), 47.01 MiB | 37.00 KiB/s   


                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)

                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1761)

                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)

                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:442)

                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:655)

                at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1152)

                at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1192)

                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:120)

                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:90)

                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:77)

                at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)

                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

            Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
```

Start it again, and once again, it seem to be stuck on

```
    using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket server credentials

     > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://bitbucket.org/{myid}/myapp.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

(i just replaced the above guid with myid)

I don't know what this repo will not work where others will. The only difference is that, this one being my real app, there is a lot more check-ins and files, but cloning anywhere else with git it works fine.

### Update 4

The above "Receiving objects" only seemed to happen after it timed out after 10 minutes.

I uploaded the project into a new Bitbucket repo, and this did not work either. Only very small test projects seem to work.

It can always connect and add the Jenkins file, but just does not seem to be able to checkout my project.

I can see no error logging anywhere! It just hangs there with no feedback on what it is trying to do.

I also tried just doing a generic Git pipeline, and this didn't work either. Is there any way to get more verbose information on what is going on under the hood?

### Update 5

I uploaded the problem repo to another Git provider (GitLab), and I can clone it from there via Jenkins no problems at all (it just worked straight away).

So, the problem seems to be with Bitbucket, which only seemed to work for some other very small test projects.

I would still be interested in know how to get any extra error log information, so I can see what is actually going wrong.

Comment: What version of Bitbucket are you using?

Comment: It is the online (cloud) Bitbucket. Not sure is this has a version? (could not fine one anywhere)

Comment: I recently had a similar issue and needed more logs from GIT to help debug. You can set the environment variable 'GIT_TRACE' to a value of '1'. This can either been done on the jenkins agent as a system environment variable... or I believe you can do it on the Jenkins UI.